# Why do my Ruby / Sinatra methods not print all the strings to the screen?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am programming a game in my spare time for fun and to try to show off my knowledge to my teachers. When I call this method in sinatra, it knows how many hits you chose if it is more than 2 it will only add 1 hit to your acid amount, then tell you how much it added . However if you choose more than 2 hits it should also tell you you can only start with 1 or 2 and the message stating that. However its not showing the first message or the second one. it just tells the message stating either 1 or 2 hits was added . any ideas on why or how to fix it?

My back-end

```
class Trippy_methods

def start_with_amount(hits)
    "You wanna start with 1 or 2 hits?"
@acid_amount = 0

    if hits == 2
         @acid_amount += 2
    else @acid_amount += 1
        "You may only start with 1 or 2 Hits...Ill give you the 1 hit for now. Don't Worry you will get more as time progresses  "
    end
        "You Started off with taking #{@acid_amount} hits of acid....Enjoy"
end
end
```

In my front-end

```
post '/stick_out_tounge' do
tounge = params[:tounge]
name = session[:name]
session[:hits] = params[:hits]
hits = session[:hits].to_i
  if tounge == "Yes"
    erb :stick_out_your_tounge, :locals => {:yes => you_say.ok_to_acid, :places => trippy_messages.places_acid_on_tounge, :leave => trippy_messages.dosed_now_leave?, 
                                            :start_amount => trippy_methods.start_with_amount(hits) }

elsif tounge == "No"
    erb :chillathome2, :locals => {:message1 => "You Say \" Gee I don't know man why what is it ?......\"", 
                                   :stick_out_tounge => "Dave says to you... \"Hey #{session[:name]} if you need to know than it wont be as fun..... \"", 
                                   :doyou => "Do you still wanna know what it is ?"}
end
end
```

Comment: The back end has random strings inserted in the source that do nothing except evaluate. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Yes those are the messages that I want it display if that condition is met, and the first string is the start message to ask how much you want

Comment: and it works perfectly fine in irb if i include puts , which i cant in sinatra

Comment: You need to pass the strings to the view layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods in ruby always return the last evaluated expression. So, in your example you have

```
def start_with_amount(hits)
  "You wanna start with 1 or 2 hits?"
  @acid_amount = 0

  if hits == 2
    @acid_amount += 2
  else @acid_amount += 1
    "You may only start with 1 or 2 Hits...Ill give you the 1 hit for now. Don't Worry you will get more as time progresses  "
  end
  "You Started off with taking #{@acid_amount} hits of acid....Enjoy" # <- This is the last evaluated expression. 
end
```

So no matter what the method does, it will *always* return `"You Started off with taking #{@acid_amount} hits of acid....Enjoy"`

The solution is to move `""You wanna start with 1 or 2 hits?"` out of the method, and send it to the view separately, and display it before the user selects how many hits they want.

To fix the other message no displaying, you need to fix your conditions.

```
def start_with_amount(hits)
  @acid_amount = 0
  result = "You Started off with taking #{@acid_amount} hits of acid....Enjoy"
  if hits == 2
    @acid_amount += 2
  elsif hits == 1
    @acid_amount += 1
  else
    result = "You may only start with 1 or 2 Hits...Ill give you the 1 hit for now. Don't Worry you will get more as time progresses  "
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: Thanks I kinda went a little bit of a different I ended up taking out the strings and just putting them in to a method by themselves and just called the method need  when i needed to display that string, but I like this better.